# Sending an email at a specific time using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, email

in the application I am developing I can specify an expiration date of a license and now I want to create an a java spring boot api that can send an email to a specific email before a specific time period (the user can choose the time period). The purpose of the email is to notify the user that his license is about to end.

For example:
The user chooses an expiration date of 3/8/2023 and chooses to be notified 3 months before the expiration date chosen. An email gets sent to the user's email on 3/5/2023 notifying the user that the license is about to end.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please understand that you are expected to perform one or more searches before asking a question here. I am sure yours will turn up something useful. Look for more tips and expectations in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to store the info in database. So that your system knows when to send the email. For ex, having two columns in a table like send_notif_date, send_to_user.
2. write a job(you can use Quartz for this) which will pick all details of user for which we need to send the emails based on if today equalsTo send_notif_date